# how to convert String in arduino library to std::string in c++

Tags: c++, string, esp32, arduino-c++

I have problem converting a String to std::string, to pass it to my function as the sample of my code is

```
String dataString = configFile.readString();
rawData = simplifyData("try to fetch data as string from dataString");
```

Comment: What is a "normal string"? Do you mean `std::string` or `const char*` or something else?

Comment: i mean std::string sorry i have edit it in the question

Comment: Can you even use `std::string` on an Arduino? I was under the impression it's not implemented there due to the special requirements of the used hardware. And why can you not change your function to accept the `String` object directly?

Comment: But assuming you can actually use `std::string`, simply using the constructor which accepts a `const char*` should work, e.g.: `simplifyData(dataString.c_str());`

Comment: @UnholySheep it was pretty hard to switch to String as most of the code is std::string and stringstream dependent and I tried to switch to String but so many bugs. on the other hand c_str() works very good thx for the help i appreciate it a lot and if u don't mind to post it as an answer to admit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `std::string` has a constructor accepting a `const char*` as parameter you can copy your `String` by using this, e.g.:

```
rawData = simplifyData(std::string(dataString.c_str()));
```

Or, since this constructor is implict, you can simplify it in your function call, such as

```
rawData = simplifyData(dataString.c_str());
```